# Is there a redis client in C or C++ which supports streaming reads?

Tags: c++, redis, streaming

We're considering using redis as a caching system for intermediate calculation results for large data sets. For example we might process a 1GB file and turn it into a 512MB set of data which would be streamed to a client. The issue is that when we request data from redis, we wouldn't want to wait until all 512MB got sent to the server before starting to send it to the client. I've looked at a couple of C and C++ libraries for redis (redox, redis3m), and even the async ones appear to give you a callback when the entire result is returned, not as portions of it are returned from the cache. Are there any which give you values a buffer at a time?

Update: This is a type of interface that I was hoping to get. Example is simplified for clarity;

```
Socket clientSocket;
/* some code that has accepted a connection from a client */
/*  ....... */

RedisClient cl;
cl.Connect("server");
cl.GetValueAsync(
    "largePreCalculated", // key
    [clientSocket](char *buffer, int bytesAvailable) {
         clientSocket.write(buffer, bytesAvailable);
    }, // callback when data from the value has come over the wire
    [clientSocket]() {
         clientSocket.close();
    } // callback when all data from value has been received
);
```

Comment: Interesting question - I surely would like to hear suggestions. However, this is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Can you break up the data? Seems like you could make it "partially streaming" rather easily by doing it in small pieces if the data supports that.

Comment: Using redis bitmaps? It is limited to 512mo though. You push buffers 1024 by 1024 for instance, store in a key the index where you can read the bitmap, optionnally you calculate a MD5 or SHA1 to check bytes. Then the client try to get the bitmap values up to the index. Something like that?

Comment: @Pradhan, what makes this off-topic?

Comment: Questions asking for library suggestions are off-topic on SO. Am on a mobile right now and am unable to point you the help page.

Comment: @zenbeni - 512 MB which I know is the limit for strings and bitmaps would be fine, but I wanted to know if there were clients where you could request a value, which might be 512MB, but get callbacks, say 1024k at a time, until all of the data is read. I don't want to have to wait until all 512MB is transferred from the redis server to our middle tier before sending it to the client.

Comment: @Tim - I'd rather not break it up, since that would mean multiple requests for each part of the data.

Comment: Sure it would mean multiple requests, but I mean it's not like the response comes in as one big packet anyways. All network layers build on the concept of breaking data into bite sized "packets" for transmission. So as long as the chunks are decent sized, it shouldn't add significant overhead. Besides, It also would add a layer of reliability/resilience since if a chunk failed you could restart that instead of the whole data set. 512MB is an aweful lot to have to restart because of a network hiccup.

Comment: Redis is single threaded. You can't do both concurrently except maybe on a redis cluster. So yo will have to cut your data and do multiple requests to do so.

Comment: @Tim, I'm assuming that redis uses TCP, which means I'm not too worried about dropping a connection due to a network hiccup. If I'm having network hiccups between my redis cache and middleware which are long enough to kill a TCP connection, I'm pretty screwed anyway.

Comment: Not if you have application layer retries. Think of downloads in the old days they were one atomic action. You couldn't restart if something went wrong, TCP/IP or not you were out of luck if the connection dies. Then came along download managers, and now pretty much every browser has built in application layer chunking and retries.  Generally speaking TCP is pretty resilient, but there isn't much harm in additional resilience especially when it helps you response time problem as well.

Comment: @zenbeni Redis's threading model shouldn't have any impact. I want my middleware, which is making a call to the redis server, to give me the data as it's read off the socket instead of collecting it all into a single buffer and returning.

Comment: @Tim - Adding resiliency doesn't mean that you have to give up performance. Think about it this way, what if http had a limit of returning 100 bytes in the response. Sure, you can break your responses down into a ton of requests, but it's not as efficient. I'm going to clarify what I'm looking for in the question.

Comment: As far as I know redis can't execute two queries at the same time against the memory store. So writing with reading concurrently cannot happen in redis. I think you have to make it like micro-batching as streaming seems impossible to me.

Comment: @zenbeni, the number of commands that redis supports shouldn't impact the redis client. The client shouldn't have to wait for the entire result to be transferred until it can do something with the data.

Answer (score 0):

*disclaimer: I'm the author of bredis*

Try to look at [bredis](https://github.com/basiliscos/cpp-bredis). While it does not allows you to get data **before** reply from redis is received over wire (it has to be parsed, right?), it returns almost **raw** (possibly fragmented) boost::asio buffers, aimed for minimal memory reallocations.

PS. Redis protocol (and C++ clients) support [pipelining](https://redis.io/topics/pipelining), i.e. simultaneous reading and writing to socket.